# Differences in ecdf() and Ecdf() on R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot this kind of [behaviour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/estimating-alpha-parameter-in-a-stable-distribution) of a data set. I have tried with Ecdf()

```
library(Hmisc)
dd<-read.table('critical.1.dat',head=F)
cdf<-Ecdf(dd$V1)
df<-hist(dd$V1)
ll<-((1-cdf$y[df$mids])/(df$density))
plot(df$mids,ll)
```

and seems all goes fine. After this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30858/cumulative-distribution-in-r) i have tried with ecdf()

```
dd<-read.table('critical.1.dat',head=F)
cdf<-ecdf(dd$V1)
df<-hist(dd$V1)
ll<-(1-cdf(df$mids))/df$density
plot(df$mids,ll)
```

and the outcome looks very different Ecdf().

Where is my mistake? why they looks me different?

First Edit: My actual code is

```
library(Hmisc)
dd<-read.table('critical.1.dat',head=F)

cdf<-Ecdf(dd$V1)
ccdf<-ecdf(dd$V1)

df<-hist(dd$V1)

ll<-((1-cdf$y[df$mids])/(df$density))
llc<-(1-ccdf(df$mids))/df$density

par( mfrow = c( 2, 1 ) )

plot(df$mids,ll,ylab='Ecdf()')
plot(df$mids,llc,ylab='ecdf()')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ecdf` returns a list while `ecdf` returns a function:

```
> set.seed(1)
> ch <- rnorm(1000, 200, 40)
> Echol <- Ecdf(ch, xlab="Serum Cholesterol")
> e.chol <- ecdf(ch)
> str(Echol)
List of 2
 $ x: num [1:1001] 79.7 79.7 80.1 82.4 84.4 ...
 $ y: num [1:1001] 0 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009 ...
 - attr(*, "N")=List of 2
  ..$ n: num 1000
  ..$ m: num 0

> e.chol <- ecdf(ch)   
> str(e.chol)
function (v)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "ecdf" "stepfun" "function"
 - attr(*, "call")= language ecdf(ch)
```

To summarize the comments below ... the list representation of an ECDF needs a different access method than the functional representation. So at least one of the the mistakes was in using df$mids in `cdf$y[df$mids]` when processing the return object from `Ecdf()`. The beauty of the base::ecdf function is that it can process an X value directly, whereas the list representation will need to use a function like `findInterval()` to construct an appropriate index.

Comment: Indeed i use them in different ways. Known that, the question is why returns me different plots, while they have to returns me the same output?

Comment: You would get an error in the first code section if you started from a clean session. You are probably mixing up your objects because you are naming them the same in both testing sections.

Comment: The same name are used here only for sake of simplicity. My actual code names that variables in different ways and i do not get any kind of error. May be a problem of different binning size during the evaluation of cumulative distribution?

Comment: The code I used creates a df$mids vector that has negative values. That's what throws the error.  As such it suggests you are inappropriately using it as an index. Perhaps you need to use `seq_along(df$mids)`, or if that doesn't work, then you need to post a reproducible example.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. My sample only has positive values. You could try with a pareto distributed sample.

Comment: The point you are studiously avoiding is that the mid-values are not appropriate indices for the value returned by `Ecdf`. You need to use findInterval or some other function that lets you do a look-up process into a list!